# how do I kill this bash script?

Tags: linux, bash

I have written a bash script, A, that is calling another script, B, over 1000 times in a loop.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> kills only script B, only one iteration. Script A keeps running and calling script B again.

Can I rewrite something in these scripts so that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will kill script A?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can trap your killing signal and do whatever you want (killing A instead of B, for instance). See [here](http://www.felixgers.de/teaching/shells/trap.html) how.
If you use it in B, try making it kill its parent...

Answer (score 0):

The correct thing to do is to ensure that both scripts are executed in the same *process group*. Then they both will get `SIGINT` signal when you press `Ctrl-C`.

From what you tell, for some reason they got into the different process groups. This may happen if the shell which executes script A thinks that it (the shell) is interactive. It's hard to tell more from your description -- feel free to paste some sample code (and describe how you launch the scripts) and we'll take a look.